# OLD HTML Frames

Tags: html, frames

I'm working on a project, where we are redirecting users to an external store in a different domain (we don't have access to that code). And I'm looking for a way to have a "thing" or anything to bring the user back to our main domain.

Remember the old framing system where you could click on an external link and you could have your info on top of the page and the content below, and you could click a "close this frame" link and it would be gone?

I remember Google used it for a while. 
Right now that the only way that I have figured out to bring the users back.

does anybody remember that HTML tag or that method of doing it? I forgot what it's called.

Or if anybody has another idea on how to execute what I'm trying to achieve, I'm all ears :)

---

Don't you guys remember when you tried searching for something (back when yahoo was #1), and most of the results were in a frame that you needed to close because it was annoying, but most porn sites just redirected you to their site so that you didn't see the frame?

Comment: Erm, an iframe? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: No, it wasn't iFrames, it was something that you added to either the <frame> tag or <a>, I totally forgot.

Answer (score 1):

Iframe or a frameset with two vertically stacked frames.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset

You give each frame a name and then you can use a target attribute on your links to specify in which frame to launch them.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to use something along the lines of

```
<a href="page.htm" target="_top">
```

Comment: Please note the old-fashioned `.htm` extension, too!  :)